# How to get the user Check-In / post with location process from facebook in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve the user Check-In or post with location info from face book in iOS (Objective C).

This is the sample code, I have tried and I did not get any success on this.

Could please review this and share some ideas to proceed further on this.

Note : I am trying to use GraphAPI.

Code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:@{@"place":@"fbuser-id"}  HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { 
      //verify result
if(error) { 
       NSLog(@"Error publishing story."); 
     } 
else { 
        NSLog(@"Story published.");
     } 
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this...from this code you got location of you check-in

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
    initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
           parameters:@{ @"fields": @"place",@"limit": @"200",}
           HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(%@,result);
}];
```

[image]

if you don't have 'user_posts' permission..then fb not provide any data.

Comment: Thank you Maulik for your reply. I'll try it and let you know update.

Comment: if you want to any help then tell me

Comment: you got your solution or not?

Comment: request for user_posts permission's approval is still pending.

Comment: after approval of permissions, I wanna post to fb where check-in or a map with present location and some description must be there. And could you please help me with graph explorer code too.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/108895529478793?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dplace%26limit%3D10&version=v2.5

Comment: open this link for checking response then click on submit

Comment: Got it. Thank you Maulik.